# iOS messages to iMessage (Mac)

Tags: iphone, messages, ios

I have recently moved from an android phone to an iPhone 5.  I have successfully moved all of my text messages from my android to the iPhone using the "Move to iOS" application from the Google play store.

I have made an iTunes backup of the messages, phones, etc. to my MacBook Pro.  Using 3rd party software, I am able to see all of my messages that are on my iPhone via the backup on my Mac.

Does anyone know of anyway to have the conversations imported to the Mac's iMessage application?  I know that the messages are found in ~/Library/Message/Archive/ directory with 3 database files found one level up from that.  I have attempted to save SMS.db from the iPhone backup and rename it chat.db.  However, it does not recreate the messages so I think there is more to the story than a simple renaming.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible.

Move the `sms.db` and `Attachments` from your phone. They are located at `/var/mobile/Library/SMS/` or you can extract them from a backup made by iTunes.

On your Mac, move the contents of `~/Library/Messages` to a backup location.

Copy the `sms.db` and `Attachments` folder to `~/Library/Messages`

Using an SQLite browser such as [DB Browser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) open the sms.db file and execute the following to change location of attachments:

`UPDATE attachment
SET filename = replace(filename, '/Library/SMS/Attachments/', '/Library/Messages/Attachments/')
WHERE filename LIKE '%/Library/SMS/Attachments/%';`

Rename `sms.db` to `chat.db`

Then you should delete the folder `~/Library/containers/com.apple.iChat` and restart. You are now done.

Source: https://denbeke.be/blog/mac/exporting-messages-and-attachments-from-iphone-to-mac/

Answer (score 0):

You tried backing up to computer, but did you try syncing? iMessage should auto sync over iCloud, however, SMS Forwarding might not be sent to your computer. It is best you upgrade to iOS 9 and OS X El Capitan first.

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible. If you have enabled it future messages will be available on the Mac also!

Comment: See my answer. It is absolutely possible.